# Redirect output of: yum repolist all

Tags: awk, rhel, yum, io-redirection

If you run the command: `yum repolist all` you will see there are basically four columns of data. repo id, repo name, status, install count. If however your run something like: `yum repolist all > repolist.txt 2>&1` the repo name column is missing. Yum does use ansi codes but I'm not sure how to deal with them.

Then end goal is to get this data (repo id, repo name) into awk so that I can auto generates some html files once a month with cron.

Updated:
OS: RedHat 7.2
Yum Version: 3.4.3

Tried: 
`yum repolist --color=never > repolist.txt` -- second column is still missing
`yum repolist --color=never | perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g' > repolist.txt` -- same results
`yum -c repolist --color=never > repolist.txt` -- works but format is more complex / harder to work with

Comment: just for info, note that `yum` has been replaced by `dnf` now, since fedora 22, whatever that corresponds to in redhat numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
yum repolist all --color=never > repolist.txt
```

No matter what, you are actually only getting *three*, not *four* columns of output.  The install count is part of the status column.  The resultant file appears thus:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
 * epel: mirror.oss.ou.edu
 * extras: mirror.scalabledns.com
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.n5tech.com
repo id                repo name                                 status
C6.0-base              CentOS-6.0 - Base                         disabled
C6.0-centosplus        CentOS-6.0 - CentOSPlus                   disabled
C6.0-contrib           CentOS-6.0 - Contrib                      disabled
C6.0-extras            CentOS-6.0 - Extras                       disabled
[etc]
base                   CentOS-6 - Base                           enabled:  6,575
base-debuginfo         CentOS-6 - Debuginfo                      disabled
c6-media               CentOS-6 - Media                          disabled
centosplus             CentOS-6 - Plus                           disabled
contrib                CentOS-6 - Contrib                        disabled
*epel                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x enabled: 12,247
[etc]
```

Comment: Sorry, should have added I have tried that.

Comment: I literally tried that before posting the answer, and got the expected result.  See amended answer.

Comment: What is your yum --version show?

[root@blackhole repos]# yum --version
3.4.3

Comment: On the host I tested with, 3.2.29

Comment: My best guess is that this was a change between 3.2.29 and 3.4.3. I've worked around the issue using yum -c for now but the results of my generate files are not what I had hoped for. I'll leave this open for a couple more days. If no one can come up with a solution it'll just give me one more reason to write a nodejs app to replace reposync.